# How can we assert that two Consumer Functions are equals in Java?

Tags: java

Actually I'm trying to assert that two functions are equals. I have a method which returns a consumer function as result, and I want to assert that this one is equals to the one expected.

Example :

```
Consumer<Collection<Object>> expected = x -> x.setId(1);

Consumer<Collection<Object>> actual = myMethod(); // this method return a consumer function
```

How can I do the assertion between expected actual ?

I would appreciate any help ! Thanks

Comment: *Why* are you trying to do this?

Comment: I'm wanna check if my method is returning the right function (I'm writing some unit tests in the context of my work)

Comment: If you know what should be returned, why do you even let the method return it? I don't think this is possible in java if the interface implementations behind the functions don't override equals

Comment: @Sweeper which the best way to cover such behavior by unit test ?

Answer (score 2):

You *cannot* assert this.  Java specifically makes no guarantees about whether equality will work.

All you can do is run the function and assert that it has the effect you want.